# PySpark replace() function does not replace integer with NULL value

Tags: python, dataframe, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

**Notice: this is for Spark version 2.1.1.2.6.1.0-129**

I have a spark dataframe (Python). I would like to replace all instances of 0 across the entirety of the dataframe (without specifying particular column names), with NULL values.

The following is the code that I have written:

`my_df = my_df.na.replace(0, None)`

The following is the error that I receive:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 1634, in replace
    return self.df.replace(to_replace, value, subset)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 1323, in replace
    raise ValueError("value should be a float, int, long, string, list, or tuple")
ValueError: value should be a float, int, long, string, list, or tuple
```

Comment: `my_df.na.replace(0, None)` works fine for me (Spark 3.x) What's your Spark version?

Comment: I have spark version 2.1.1.2.6.1.0-129. I have also updated the question to include the version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently in Spark 2.1.1, `df.na.replace` [does not support](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.replace) `None`. `None` option is only available [since 2.3.0](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.replace), which is not applicable in your case.

To replace values dynamically (i.e without typing columns name manually), you can use either `df.columns` or `df.dtypes`. The latter will give you the option to compare datatype as well.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

for c in df.dtypes:
    if c[1] == 'bigint':
        df = df.withColumn(c[0], F.when(F.col(c[0]) == 0, F.lit(None)).otherwise(F.col(c[0])))

# Input
# +---+---+
# | id|val|
# +---+---+
# |  0|  a|
# |  1|  b|
# |  2|  c|
# +---+---+

# Output
# +----+---+
# |  id|val|
# +----+---+
# |null|  a|
# |   1|  b|
# |   2|  c|
# +----+---+
```